# mysql not installing

Tags: python, mysql, django, visual-studio-code

I am getting error while installing mysql in virtual environment.But why?If i run the command from cmd under env environment it installs.But from vs code showing fatal error [image]

Comment: Try using doing those command in vanilla `powershell` , bet it won't work, most likely it's a `PATH` issue. A quick fix would be changing your VsCode Terminal to CMD instead of powershell

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be in the virtual environment, you can recreate a new virtual environment and install the `mysqlclient` package again.

Or if you can successfully install it in an external cmd window, this does not affect your use in vscode.